# How to add user created data to drop down menu options

Tags: unity, c#

So I'm trying to make it that I can have a dropdown that will have user created info appear in it.

```
List<engines> engineList = new List<engines>();
public Dropdown engineSelect;

public class engines
{
    public string engineName;
    public int featureNumber;
    public int totalDevPoints;
    public string optimizedGenre;
    public engines(string name, int feature, int totalPoints, string opt)
    {
        engineName = name;
        featureNumber = feature;
        totalDevPoints = totalPoints;
        optimizedGenre = opt;

    }
}
engines playerEngine = new engines(engineName, numFeature, 0, whatGenre);
```

Pretend player set engineName, numFeature, and whatGenre with text fields. 
I wanted to have it that the drop down would add in whatever new engines the player makes. How would I do that? I want to have it say select engine: and then the player would pick from dropdown from engines they made(only saying engine names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), which stores your data value against a key. Whatever the data value would be and whatever the key would be. It is very flexible.

You can use `Dictionary` for that purpose. With `Key-Value` pair of `string` and `engines`. Add all engines in that `Dictionary` against their names. Then add only names in list and upon selecting, get engine corresponding to that name.

For example,

```
// Declaring Dictionary for engines against string key.
Dictionary<string,engines> _dEngines = new Dictionary<string,engines>();

// Creating list of string in which each value will represent the relative engine.
List<string> engineList = new List<string>();

public Dropdown engineSelect;

public class engines
{
    public string engineName;
    public int featureNumber;
    public int totalDevPoints;
    public string optimizedGenre;
    public engines(string name, int feature, int totalPoints, string opt)
    {
        engineName = name;
        featureNumber = feature;
        totalDevPoints = totalPoints;
        optimizedGenre = opt;

    }
}

engines playerEngine = new engines(engineName, numFeature, 0, whatGenre);

// Adding engine to dictionary
_dEngines.Add("Engine1",playerEngine);
```

Now upon selecting from Dropdown item, let say if you select `"Engine1"` then you can get value by,

```
engines selectedEngine = _dEngines["Engine1"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it did work then please mark it as answer so that other users also can get some benefits from this answer.